# Permission for php cross domain include file

Tags: php, cpanel

A php script process.php is called by a form submit and a cross domain php script common.php is included by process.php. I got below error.

```
Warning:  require_once(/home/m64/public_html/hosting/example.com/libs/common.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/example_b.com/public_html/m/process.php on line 13

Fatal error:  require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/home/m64/public_html/hosting/example.com/libs/common.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/example_b.com/public_html/m/process.php on line 13
```

example.com and example_b.com are different domains but on same server. Both domains are on separated cPanel accounts. I have full access control to both cPanel. How can I grant the permission right to each domain for file access?

Answer (score 0):

try using a full path like this: http://www.domain1.com/libs/common.php

Comment: it is a sample link, not a reference to external docs/code, so I'm voting OK